# swift deinit method not calling

Tags: ios, swift4.2, deinit

In `UIViewController` `deinit` method not calling in ios swift4.2

I have tried below code for navigate to next `viewController` after navigation in `popToViewcontroller` `deinit` method not calling.

```
 let data = isSearchEnabled ? repository.filteredList[index] : repository.list[index]
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    (appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController).tabBar.isHidden = true
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AuctionDetailsViewController") as! AuctionDetailsViewController
    viewController.auction = data.getAuctionData()
    viewController.parentVC = self
    parentNavigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

PushView :

```
deinit {
    print("AuctionDetailsViewController deallocated...")
}
```

The above `deinit`  method should be call on `popToViewcontroller`

Comment: Please add the code of the `AuctionDetailsViewController`. I'm quite sure the problem is that your `parentVC` variable there is not `weak`

Comment: @MarcoPace thanks ,         weak var parentVC : UIViewController?    declared in AuctionDetailsViewController .

Answer (score 2):

You need to aware about the memory management done ay iOS using ARC. You can read this [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

**Deinit() is not called, if viewcontoller...**

> **holds the strong reference of an object(retain cycle)**
>
> > you need to check and remove the unnecessary strong references to an object to avoid retail cycle
>
> **has notification observer**
>
> > you need to unregister an observer because the notification center retains the observer until you unregister it.
>
> **uses of delegates (hold the strong reference of it)**
>
> > if view controller is confirming the protocol that delegate should be marked as `weak`.

The above mentioned are the some points that prevents the view controller to dealloc and deinit is never called. There may be other points reason too for the same.

Comment: Thanks for solution , I tried above what you mentioned , still i am facing same issue .

Comment: For me, a Timer was causing the issue. Timer must be invoked on the main thread, and should be optional. Swift Timer is a buggy class.